# How can I make an AJAX call that periodically refreshes a part of the page?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am working in a chat system that relies on a mysql database.

At the beginning of the first loading of the page sending the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM `Shoutbox` ORDER BY `Shoutbox`.`ID` ASC LIMIT 0 , 30
```

and then using a while loop mold all messages (with user names and date) in a div.

```
while($array=mysql_fetch_array($dati)) {         
                    echo "<div class='tag_li $array[ID]'><span class='when'>$array[DateTime]</span><span class='linea mess'><span id='author'><a onclick='ajaxLoadContent(this)' link='profile.php?name=$array[User]'>$array[User]</a></span>: $array[Message]</span></div>";
                }
```

Now I would like to be sent every second query, and then updates the contents of the div with new messages if any.

How can I send a SQL query in a range?

Comment: Do you mean "How can I make an AJAX call that periodically refreshes a part of the page?"

Comment: You can't do this with pure PHP (at least not clean). PHP will be executed when the page is requested, you could use a sleep method to delay the end of PHP execution, but that is not really what you should do. Instead look up AJAX, it is quite easy with libraries like jQuery

Comment: How do I using AJAX to make a request to the database and then send SQL queries?

Answer (score 0):

I will assume you are using javascript and want to make an ajax call.

Start with the timer on the client side

```
window.setInterval("ajaxFunction()",milliseconds);
```

And the ajax function

```
function ajaxFunction(){
    var ajaxRequest;  // The variable that makes Ajax possible!

    try{
        // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari
        ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } catch (e){
        // Internet Explorer Browsers
        try{
            ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e) {
            try{
                ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e){
                // Something went wrong
                alert("Your browser broke!");
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    // Create a function that will receive data sent from the server
    ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
            var ajaxDisplay = document.getElementById('ajaxDiv');
            ajaxDisplay.innerHTML = ajaxDisplay.innerHTML + ajaxRequest.responseText;
        }
    }

    ajaxRequest.open("GET", "ajax-example.php" , true);
    ajaxRequest.send(null); 
}
```

the php part

```
while($array=mysql_fetch_array($dati)) {         
                echo "<div class='tag_li $array[ID]'><span class='when'>$array[DateTime]</span><span class='linea mess'><span id='author'><a onclick='ajaxLoadContent(this)' link='profile.php?name=$array[User]'>$array[User]</a></span>: $array[Message]</span></div>";
            }
```

And the html part

```
<div id="ajaxDiv"></div>
```

That should give you an idea  how it is done.

Comment: I already use AJAX for other purposes. But in this case I do not understand how to make a request to the database. In short, instead of 'ajax-example.php' where proceeds posts?

Comment: You just make the request to the page ajax-example.php that is somewhere on your server. And that page will query the database, return the result, and echo them out. After you have done that ajaxRequest.responseText holds the output of that page.

Comment: I get it. Access is efficient? Fast?

Comment: Depends on your implementation, and number of users using it.

Comment: I understood. Thank you very much. In case you do not succeed even after a day, I ask in this topic right?

Comment: Any time ^^ I also recommend that you use a framework ex Jquery to handle your calls. Much easier.